# Roland E-16 Midi Out

Tags: midi, keyboard

Any ideas on how to set the keyboard to send a midi out signal to an XV-2020?  There is no midi switch on the E-16 and the available manuals on-line do no show a complete midi implementation.  There is an appendix Midi Guide that is not available online.

The manual describes connecting using midi cables only.  On other keyboards, there is typically a toggle switch to enact the midi out.

I cant find any reference in the manual on how to do this / set this.  The midi signal (green light) shows up on the XV2020 but no sound comes from the keyboard.

Is there a setting on the e16 that needs to be used to enable midi?

Manual: http://www.synthmanuals.com/manuals/roland/e-16/owners_manual/e-16_om.pdf

The manual describes connecting using midi cables only.  On other keyboards, there is typically a toggle switch to enact the midi out.  I cant find any reference in the manual on how to do this / set this.  The midi signal (green light) shows up on the XV2020 but no sound comes from the keyboard.  Is there a setting on the e16 that needs to be used to enable midi?

Comment: What did you try? The connection shown in the manual, or the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

According to the implementation chart MIDI channels are "unchangeable" (look at the note below the channel legend cell in first row). So no, there is nothing to setup.

Set the External module (the XV-2020) to OMNI if possible, otherwise set it to listen to one of the channels listed in the implementation chart:
[image: Roland E-16 MIDI Implementation Chart]

Answer (score 0):

I owned one of these and worked on MIDI files.  As I recall, the E-16 transmits whatever you are playing on your keyboard to MIDI Channel 4.  When you use the built-in accompaniment, the accompaniment will all be transmitted.  So if you want your receiving device to only receive what you are playing on the keyboard, put your receiving device to listen to channel 4 only.